how to set accuracy within mizani.labels.percent()
Can I use mizani.label.percent or another mizani formatter to present the geom_label with one decimal place? The code below works but rounds to an integer.
import polars as pl
from plotnine import * 
import mizani.labels as ml

df = pl.DataFrame({
  "group": ["A", "B"], 
  "rate": [.511, .634]
})

(
    ggplot(df, aes(x="group", y="rate", label="ml.percent(rate)"))
    + geom_col()
    + geom_label()
    + scale_y_continuous(labels=ml.percent)
)


(
    ggplot(df, aes(x="group", y="rate", label="ml.percent(rate, accuracy=.1)"))
    + geom_col()
    + geom_label()
    + scale_y_continuous(labels=ml.percent)
)

When doing this, I get the following error:
PlotnineError: "Could not evaluate the 'label' mapping: 'ml.percent(rate, accuracy=.1)' (original error: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accuracy')"


After experimenting with it for quite a bit, I found a solution:
You can directly format the labels within geom_label to achieve the desired percentage display:
import polars as pl
from plotnine import * 
import mizani.labels as ml

df = pl.DataFrame({
  "group": ["A", "B"], 
  "rate": [.511, .634]
})

(
    ggplot(df, aes(x="group", y="rate", label="rate"))
    + geom_col()
    + geom_label(format_string='{:.1%}')
    + scale_y_continuous(labels=ml.percent)
)

Result:

Additionally, you could replace the mizani formatting on the y-axis like this to achieve the same result:
import polars as pl
from plotnine import * 

df = pl.DataFrame({
  "group": ["A", "B"], 
  "rate": [.511, .634]
})

(
    ggplot(df, aes(x="group", y="rate", label="rate"))
    + geom_col()
    + geom_label(format_string='{:.1%}')
    + scale_y_continuous(labels=lambda l: ["{:.1f}%".format(v * 100) for v in l])
)

